# return EMPTY crash my redux observable chain

Tags: redux, rxjs, redux-observable

I am using redux, redux-observable.

I have the following

```
import { EMPTY, Observable } from "rxjs";

const setCurrentDatastoreIdEpic = (action$, state$): Observable<any> => action$.pipe(
    ofType(DatastoreActions.setCurrentDatastoreId),
    map((action: {payload: {datastoreId: string}}) => {
        if(action.payload.datastoreId) {
            return ItemsActions.getItemsListRequest({
                datastoreId: action.payload.datastoreId,
                page: 1,
            });
        } else {
            return EMPTY;
        }
    })
);
```

But everytime I go in the else I have

> Uncaught Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware
>   for async actions.

But they say to use EMPTY if there is no action dispatched.

I also tried `Observable.empty()` but it say that empty do not exist in Observable (and this way is deprecated from what I saw)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you're using operator `map` and inside that you're returning `EMPTY`. `EMPTY` is an Observable that emits no `next` notification and emits just one `complete` notification. But `map` doesn't care what you return from its projection functions so it takes `EMPTY` and passes it further where `redux-observable` complains because `EMPTY` is not an action.

So instead of `map` you can use `concatMap` (or `mergeMap` would work as well) and wrap `ItemsActions.getItemsListRequest` with `of()`. Returning `EMPTY` into `concatMap` is perfectly correct.

```
concatMap((action: {payload: {datastoreId: string}}) => {
    if(action.payload.datastoreId) {
        return of(ItemsActions.getItemsListRequest({
            datastoreId: action.payload.datastoreId,
            page: 1,
        }));
    } else {
        return EMPTY;
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the explenation, what about if I return something like this ? 
`return ({ type: 'NO DATASTORE SELECTED'})` It does work, but is it a good practice ?

Comment: If you have an epic that is _'read-only'_ (e.g. you do not want to return an action from it), you can return `ignoreElements()`, which is like returning an empty observable, but is the approach recommended by the [official docs](https://redux-observable.js.org/docs/Troubleshooting.html#it-seems-like-your-epics-are-not-responding-to-actions).

Comment: This epic conditionaly doesn't return anything. `ignoreElements()` will ignore always everything.

Answer (score 0):

in addition to this if you just want some action epic do nothing with the store you can use `ignoreElements()` instead of `map`